# How to know or database record was deleted

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I'm starting some php workers at the same time and each of them takes a job to do. These jobs are written in database table and when worker takes one - it deletes the record. My code:

```
$job = Job::first();
if (!empty($job) and $job->delete()==true) {
// so something
}
```

But the problem is that still some workers take the same $job to perform at the same time! How this can happen?

UPDATE

I'm using Postgres Database

Comment: Are you using the built-in queue workers or some custom stuff? Is your code some pseudo-code to demonstrate the issue or is it actual code you wrote? I'm asking because Laravel has you covered with all this already...

Comment: Although I provided a proven working answer, to Namoshek's point, Laravel has a robust queuing system.  Even in a small cluster a minimal Redis server running somewhere would let you use it without having to worry about the issue you are seeing.  See https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queues

Comment: I'm not sure Laravel Jobs/quene are good choice for us, because we are working with 10 workers at the time with non-stopable php processess. Each process takes up to 1min and then starts again. Is it a good decision to solve it with Laravel tools?
For us it would be more clear to write some script, because who knows what implementations we will need in a future, because App is working with really huge database and a lot of records

Comment: The Laravel queue system is designed for exactly this. If your tasks weren't long running, you wouldn't need to run them in the background anyway, right? -- You should really have a thorough look at the queue system, it comes with some really good features. For example you can define different queues, e.g. for different priorities. You can also assign queue workers to specific queues, which means you could also have one worker for a queue with short jobs and a bunch of workers for a queue with very long jobs, like you describe it. Then they wouldn't even interfere with each other.

Comment: Thank you for your information @Namoshek. I wasn't sure how this works in our case, but now I understand we can use them. Thanks again. But for now your submited answer worked really great. no duplicates!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Despite above comments seeking for a better solution, you should be able to solve it this way:

```
$job = Job::first();
if ($job && Job::where('id', $job->id)->delete()) {
    // do something else ...
}
```

Explanation: `Job::where('id', $job->id)->delete()` will delete all job records with the given id and return the number of affected records. This may be either `0` or `1`, or `false` and `true` respectively. So this should actually work, if your database handles the concurrent delete properly.

Comment: You don't understand the problem.

Comment: Look at your code and then look at mine, they are essentially doing the same. Although you forgot the locking in your code (a transaction does not guarantee locking and some database engines don't even support locking). His problem is that `// do something` is executed twice - deleting something that doesn't exist is no problem. ;)

Comment: You were right I left out the most important part, which I added.  Your code has the race condition, so they are not at all the same, but I did airball the key part of the SELECT, so kudos to you for responding.

Comment: Yes, my code may still be executed twice up to the point where the delete statement is executed, which is a shame but not breaking the application. It is no problem to execute `DELETE FROM jobs WHERE id = $id` twice, because the second time the entry is gone already and the `if(...)` will not be executed again. So I don't really see your race condition here.

Comment: By the way, with my comment on the question itself, I was aiming for a much better solution than proposed here. One that might work fairly well would be to use a scheduled job.

Comment: It is your opinion that trying to delete the same row 2x is not a problem, but that is the entire basis of the question.  With multiple workers it's actually a problem because instead of getting new rows to delete, the workers are hung up selecting the same row over and over and failing.

Comment: I agree that the job will most likely be executed multiple times, but it will not fail endlessly. As soon as the record is deleted, it won't be fetched anymore. Is it efficient? No, definitely not. And as I said, a scheduled job would most likely be the most appropriate solution.

Comment: You misunderstand my point.  With your strategy, the workers will often get the same row.  The more workers the more likely they will all get the same row.  It's timing related.

Comment: I have pushed changes to production. Tomorrow I will check for any duplicates! I have started from this answer, because I forgot to tell this is Postgres DB, so not sure answer before will fit... Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Very simple --- it is a race condition.

In order to avoid that you will need to implement some sort of database locking.  You didn't indicate what database you were using, so I'm going to assume that you're using MySQL.

Your select statement needs to Lock the rows you've selected.  In MySQL you do this with

```
DB::beginTransaction();

// Queries you need to make with eloquent
SELECT * FROM queue LIMIT 1 FOR UPDATE;
// use id if you got a row.  If not just commit immediately.
DELETE FROM queue WHERE id = $id;  

DB::commit();
```

Comment: Not trying to mock here, just adding it where it is appropriate: You can also use locking with the query builder (see [database query documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries#pessimistic-locking)). Meaning the by far easiest solution and least code change would have been to alter `Job::first()` to `Job::lockForUpdate()->first()`. It would then also be compiled for different SQL systems accordingly. But I never tried this before, so no idea if it really works that easy.

Comment: @Namoshek Sounds like a decent solution.  I don't use Laravel very often, and it's been expanded on quite a bit since I last did, but it's quite likely that code would at least solve the problem and improve concurrency is we make assumptions about what the Job class does.